# Can parent module directives be used in child modules like controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-module

Just as `controllers` are module "level" independent and can be used anywhere in the entire application stack I am wondering if there is a way for child module to use the parent modules directives without having to assign them as dependency for each child module.

Example of how I was hoping to have directives work (in the view of a `controller`):

```
angular.module('app.child').config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('child', {
    url: '/child',
    views: {
      'header': {
        controller: 'parentController',
        templateUrl: 'child.html'
      }
    }
  });
});

angular.module('app').controller('parentController', function () {
  console.log('test');
});
```

So what I am wondering is if

```
angular.module('app', ['app.child']);
angular.module('app.child', ['ui.router']);
```

can also be written as

```
angular.module('app', ['app.child', 'ui.router']);
angular.module('app.child', []);
```

in some way where `ui.router` is still available for the child module.

If I do this in my existing project I get `$injector` errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just as controllers are module "level" independent and can be used
>   anywhere

This is true and that is something you should never do.
Module should be self-consistent and independent from parent modules - it should declare all required dependencies.

I.e. if you have 2 modules: app and app.child, and in some place in app.child you have: `<div ui-sref=...` than your app.child must depend on ui-router.
(This will still work if it doesnt, but parent does - but this does not mean that this is correct way)

N.B. A lot of apps can leave within single module. Are you sure you need more than one?

Comment: I've just heard that using multiple modules is good practice when building applications, so I wanted to make the ground structure good. However does it slow my application down a lot if I have, lets say, 5 child modules, and each of them use, lets say, `ui-router` as dependency? Or should I somehow group them together?

Comment: no, it doesnt slow you may have same dependency multiple times - its ok. Using multiple modules  - just same as multiple projects in Maven/JAVA, you may have them, you may not. This is more about code organization until you share your code between multiple apps/users. (Like npm/bower)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, I sure will keep that in mind :)